# In a list view, how do I filter a Person column to find invalid values?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, column

We have a SharePoint list. A column on the list is of the type "Person or Group". The field is set to allow "People only", chosen from "All Users". How do I create a view to find old list items where this field now contains a user who is no longer active or valid?

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to filter inactive user with list view, we could only filter people by fixed user name or current user.

As a workaround, you could find and clean up the orphaned Users(the user has been removed in AD) with powershell.

Please refer to https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/find-and-delete-orphaned-users-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

Comment: The users no longer exist in SharePoint, either. An attempt to edit any of these list items results in a save error because the value of the person field isn't valid.